# naming array from an array in GAWK

Tags: arrays, gawk

I have a file with repeating elements.  I would like to assign records to an array until the file repeats, at which point I want to create a new array to assign the records to.  I would like to do this an arbitrary amount of times.

for example.

```
$ cat repeat.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

I want the output to be something like this

```
0 a a a
1 b b b
2 c c c
3 d d d
4 e e e
5 f f f
6 g g g
```

right now I am doing this with this hideous code.

```
    awk 'BEGIN{n=0;z=0}
         $1~"a" {n=0;z++}
         z==1{a[n]=$0}
         z==2{b[n]=$0}
         z==3{c[n]=$0}
         z==4{d[n]=$0}
         z==5{e[n]=$0}
         z==6{f[n]=$0}
         {n++}
         END{for  (i in a) 
              print i,a[i],b[i],c[i],d[i],e[i],f[i],g[i],h[i],k[i],j[i]}'                 
         repeat.txt
```

I would like the assignment of new arrays to be automatic.

I attempted this by the following

```
 echo "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz" > alphabet.txt  

     awk  'BEGIN{N=0}
           NR==FNR{FS=""}
           NR==FNR{for (zz=0;zz<=NF;zz++) a[zz]=$zz; next} 
           NR!=FNR{FS="\t"}
           NR!=FNR{if ($0~a) N++; (a[N])[N]=$0}
           END{for (I in (a[N])) print I,(a[N])[I]}' alphabet.txt repeat.txt
```

but this didn't work because you can't do multidimensional arrays like this in gawk.  I can't think of another way to do this.

Comment: Your first solution seems workable, yes a little ugly, but how much time do you have?  I assume that `$1 ~ "a {...` is a typo? The 2nd `z==1{b..` seems to be a typo as well . I would put 2-3 tests on the same line, just to close up the code.. . . . . 2nd solution : Haven't done this in ages, but I recall that  you can do `split("abc...", charArr, "")` (splitting on a null char) to get each char separately into `charArr[]`. Also your `BEGIN` statements are superfluous. Good luck.

Comment: You were right on the typos (not sure how I had them as I took them from a working script...).  This my first method does work, but requires that I manually create as many arrays as repeats.  I just realized that the newer versions of gawk allow for multidimensional arrays, so I'll try that and report back